# Convert javascript function to Obj-C function

Tags: javascript, objective-c, function

I want to use a bunch of functions that were written in Javascript in my Obj-C app.  I made a header file and got the first one converted, but got stuck on the second.  Here's what I started with and what I've done so far that doesn't work...

```
function calcDayOfWeek(juld)
    {
        var A = (juld + 1.5) % 7;
        var DOW =     (A==0)?"Sunday":(A==1)?"Monday":(A==2)?"Tuesday":(A==3)?"Wednesday":(A==4)?"Thursday":(A==5)?"Friday":"Saturday";
        return DOW;
    }
```

...and my attempt:

```
NSString calcDayOfWeek(float julianDay)
{
    float A = (julianDay + 1.5) % 7;
    NSString DOW = (A==0)?"Sunday":(A==1)?"Monday":(A==2)?"Tuesday":(A==3)?"Wednesday":(A==4)?"Thursday":(A==5)?"Friday":"Saturday";
    return DOW;
}
```

It should return a string with the day of the week based on the input of a Julian Day Number.

EDIT:  Per Yuji's answer, this is what worked...

```
NSString* calculateDayOfWeek(float julianDay) {
    int a = fmod(julianDay + 1.5, 7);
    NSString* dayOfWeek = (a==0)?@"Sunday":(a==1)?@"Monday":(a==2)?@"Tuesday":(a==3)?@"Wednesday":(a==4)?@"Thursday":(a==5)?@"Friday":@"Saturday";
    return dayOfWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You first need to learn the syntax and the grammar of Objective-C**.
 The function would be

```
NSString* calcDayOfWeek(float julianDay)
{
     int A = ((int)(julianDay + 1.5)) % 7;
     NSString* DOW = (A==0)?@"Sunday":(A==1)?@"Monday":(A==2)?@"Tuesday":(A==3)?@"Wednesday":(A==4)?@"Thursday":(A==5)?@"Friday":@"Saturday";
     return DOW;
}
```

- In Objective-C, variables for objects are pointers, not the object itself. You need `NSString*` instead of `NSString`.
- `@"..."` is the Objective-C string which is an object. `"..."` is a C-string, which is just `char*`.
- I recommend against using `==` for a `float`. What happens if two floats differ by .00000001? Well,  `%` operator automatically gives you integer, but I still don't like it.

**However, you shouldn't re-invent the wheel**. Cocoa has an API that does the calendar conversion for you. See [Date and Time Programming Topics.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1)

Comment: Of the suggestions, this gets the closest.  But the `int A = (julianDay + 1.5) % 7;` line generates two instances of `error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'int')`

Comment: I searched for that error and tried this instead: `int A = fmod(julianDay, 7);`  This compiles fine - now to try it.  And thanks for the link to the date/time stuff!

Comment: Ah, sorry. I had no idea that `%` doesn't accept float and int!

Comment: I've been curious about this for a while and it's impossible to google: What's the difference between `NSString* calcDayOfWeek()...` in your answer and `NSString *calcDayOfWeek()...` in @ConspicuousCompiler's one? Does moving the `*` have a syntactic impact?

Comment: No it doesn't. Read the specification of the programming language C: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf Basically, any spaces to the right or to the left of non-alphabetic character mean nothing to the language. You can just remove them. `NSString*calc...` would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to build your strings [as NSStrings](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/NSString) by prefixing them with `@`s and take a reference to them:

```
NSString *calcDayOfWeek(float julianDay)
{
    float A = (julianDay + 1.5) % 7;
    NSString *DOW = (A==0)?@"Sunday":(A==1)?@"Monday":(A==2)?@"Tuesday":(A==3)?@"Wednesday":(A==4)?@"Thursday":(A==5)?@"Friday":@"Saturday";
    return DOW;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the way you declare the function. Try this:

```
-(NSString *) dayOfWeek:(float)julianDay {

    float A = (julianDay + 1.5) % 7;
    NSString *DOW = (A==0)?@"Sunday":(A==1)?@"Monday":(A==2)?@"Tuesday":(A==3)?@"Wednesday":(A==4)?@"Thursday":(A==5)?@"Friday":@"Saturday";
    return DOW;
}
```